# Lifting property of Serre fibration that is weak equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, cofibrations, homotopy-extension-property

Suppose a map of topological spaces $f$ is a Serre fibration, that is, it has the (right) homotopy lifting property with respect to every inclusion of the form $D^n\to D^n \times I$ as in the following diagram:

[image]

I am trying to prove that if $f$ is also a weak equivalence then it has the right lifting property with respect to all border inclusions of the form $S^n\to D^{n+1}$.

In addition, I would want to prove the converse, that if a map has this lifting property then it is a Serre fibration and a weak equivalence.

Here is what I have got (it is not much):

Given a commutative square
[image]

by applying the homotopy group functor $\pi_n$ at any basepoint, I get a map $$\mathbb{Z}=\pi_n(S^n) \to \pi_n(X) \to \pi_n (Y)$$ that factors though the trivial group (since $D^{n+1}$ is contractible). And since the second map is an isomorphism, then the first map $\pi_n(S^n)\to \pi_n(X)$ is trivial.

This is not of much help and I would like to know hot to use the homotopy lifting property in combination with this to prove the result.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This follows from the fact that the generating cofibrations in the Quillen model structure on $\mathbf{Top}$ are the inclusions $i: S^{n}\to D^{n+1}$ and that cofibrations have the left lifting property with respect to acyclic fibrations (i.e. fibrations which are weak equivalences).

Comment: If you would like an explicit proof see {https://math.mit.edu/~psh/notes/modcattop.pdf}.